# CSS- Efecto de pulso con UN solo color

Tags: javascript, css, css3, transition

Creo que lo que busco es fácil de entender pero no lo he logrado.

Tengo un momento en el que ocurre esto: `document.getElementbyId(id).classList.add("error");` haciendo que este elemento obtenga la clase "error", y la clase .error es esta:

```
.error{
    transition-property: background-color;
    background-color:#ff3f3f;
    transition-duration:0.5s;
}
```

Esto funciona bien ya que cuando mi código detecta un error hay una transición suave donde mi, en este caso, `<td>`   se vuelva rojo, el problema es que se queda rojo para siempre.

Lo que necesito es que este "pulso" vuelva al estado inicial de color, que es "ninguno", o lo que es lo mismo eliminar la clase (con un fadeout o transición del `.error`)

No sé muy bien cómo organizarlo ya que es un juego y al pulsar sobre una celda () errónea quiero que emita un pulso rojo y vuelva a su estado. He probado con `document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("error")` pero no me funciona, sigue en rojo para siempre.

Y el tema de las animaciones y transiciones no lo domino como quisiera.

Me valdría cualquier idea para realizar el toque de atención de "movimiento erróneo".

Adjunto el código total:
https://jsfiddle.net/bay20es4/

Gracias

PD: Efecto "Pulso" con este codigo:

```
@keyframes error-animation {
0% {  }
50% { background-color:#ff3f3f}
100% {  }
```

}

Comment: Cuanto tiempo quieres que se quede rojo?

Comment: Me gustaría que quedara en rojo como 1s o menos y que volviera con un fadeout a su estado normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ello es facil hacerlo con javascript y de igual forma con css, ejecuta una animacion solamente que dure x tiempo, reemplaza esto por todo lo que tienes en error css

```
  .error{
         animation-name: error-animation;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        -webkit-animation-name: error-animation;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    }
    @keyframes error-animation {
        0% {  }
        100% { background-color:#ff3f3f}
    }
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, quizá fallé con el "@keyframes".

Comment: que bueno que te funcione